# Hadoop Could not find or load main class

Tags: hadoop, linux-mint

i try to install hadoop from this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtOhsZ0Sb1E&t=126s
When i run the last command

```
start-all.sh
```

i got this message:

```
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh  
Starting namenodes on [localhost]  
localhost: namenode running as process 6283. Stop it first.  
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/myname/hadoop-    2.7.3/logs/hadoop-myname-datanode-MYNAME.out  
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]  
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 6379. Stop it first.  
starting yarn daemons  
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/myname/hadoop-    2.7.3/logs/yarn-myname-resourcemanager-MYNAME.out  
Error: Could not find or load main class     org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager  
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/myname/hadoop- 2.7.3/logs/yarn-myname-nodemanager-MYNAME.out  
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager
```

## my bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.3
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native"
```

## my hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>  
 <property>  
  <name>dfs.replication</name>  
  <value>1</value>  
  <description>Default block replication.  
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.   
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.  
  </description>  
 </property>  
 <property>  
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>  
  <value>file:/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>  
 </property>  
 <property>  
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>  
   <value>file:/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>  
 </property>  
</configuration>
```

## my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>  
 <property>  
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>  
  <value>/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.3/tmp</value>  
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>  
 </property>  

 <property>  
  <name>fs.default.name</name>  
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>  
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose  
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The  
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming  
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to  
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>    
 </property>  
</configuration>
```

## my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>  
 <property>  
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>  
  <value>localhost:54311</value>  
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs  
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map  
  and reduce task.  
  </description>  
 </property>  
</configuration>
```

I have tried a lot of things but the error is still there..
Any idea ?

Comment: The daemons are already running , try to stop them first with 
stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh

Comment: i tried but the error remains. except the part "stop it first"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your .bashrc file:

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/path_to_hadoop_location
```

Comment: error still remains could not find either
 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager
either
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager

Comment: i tried  this too but the error remains..  for /path_to_hadoop_location i wrote exactly the same as at HADOOP_INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

You have to include yarn-site.xml file while configuring hadoop

```
 <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml : add this also

```
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
```

I think you can resolve this issue by adding these properties.